# PowerShell Automatic Module Loading with new sessions and on-demand Module Loading

Tags: powershell, function, module

I have built a custom set of PowerShell functions and tools that I load as a Module, but this Module is quite large now and the loading times on slower systems can be 5-10 seconds as the Module is about 11,000 lines.

I was led to believe that PowerShell modules are super-efficient and simply parse the function name / parameters at load time, and so a Module should load in a fraction of a second - this is not my experience and I see quite long load-times for Modules.

Hence, I would like to split my tools up into 3 modules, one that has the functions that I always want available, one that has all of my help / FAQ functions, and one that has all of my custom setup scripts that I mostly only need on new systems, so these would be:

```
MyTools.psm1
MyHelp.psm1
MySetup.psm1
```

I would like `MyHelp.psm1` and `MySetup.psm1` to be on the system but to never load when a new PowerShell session opens, and then only to load when I activate them, e.g. by running functions `Load-MyHelp`, `Load-MySetup` that initialise the Modules.

My generic questions then come down to:

Is there a way to speed up Module loading so that large Modules do not make each PowerShell session take 5-10 seconds to load?

Is there a way to have separate Modules that do not load when a new PowerShell session loads, but instead, their functions are loaded into the current session only when I run a function to activate those Modules (and how exactly would I do that)?

Comment: If it takes more than a second to load then that would indicate the root module script file or some dependency actually _does something_ during import. 11000 lines of function declarations wouldn't take 5-10 seconds. Can you describe what happens (beyond defining functions) in your psm1 file?

Comment: I checked and it is only functions and `Set-Alias` statements. If I install this module, new PowerShell sessions take about 5-10 seconds to open and I don't know why. Do `Set-Alias` statements create an overhead to load times in some way?